# javascript show in cycle with delay

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Simple example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  console.log(i); // <--- should be show with delay in 300ms 
}
```

Simple setTimeout using of course doesn't work... I guess there's should be using closures..

Comment: not getting you, what is the question?

Comment: print i line by line with delay in 300ms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should do the job:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  (function(i) {
     setTimeout(function(){console.log(i);}, i*300);
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: Or `(i+1)*300` depending on whether the first `i` should be printed immediately or not.

Answer (score 6):

It's a simple matter of writing a recursive function:

```
function display(i)
{
  if (i == 10) return;    
  setTimeout(function(){ console.log(i); display(i+1); }, 300);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to add second parameter let's say n and then replace the if statement with: "if (i==n)". Just as matter of genericity.

Comment: As a matter of genericity, I would go as far as provide the traditional for-loop arguments : initialization, step function and condition function: function recurse(init, condition, step) { if (condition(init)) recurse(step(init), condition, step); }

Answer (score 3):

You could use setInterval, like so:

```
var i = 0;
var id = setInterval(function(){
    if (i == 9) clearInterval(id);
    console.log(i);
    i++;
}, 300);
```

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/MLWgG/2/